# Laravel5.7にバージョンアップしたところ、カラムが 'password,60' に変わり、エラーに。

Tags: laravel

Larabel5.7にバージョンアップしたところ、usersテーブルのカラム名が自動で変わった？
ようです。（それが原因か定かではなく。）

```
$table->string('password')->nullable();
↓
$table->string('password,60')->nullable();
```

そして、会員登録入力をしようとしたところ、以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
```

`password,60` というカラム名はLaravel5.7の仕様か何かなのでしょうか？

逆に、`migrate:refresh` で `$table->string('password')->nullable();` に戻すと、以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'proveider' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel側で$fillableに登録してありますか？

そしてそこ以外にnullを許容しないけどdefault値が設定されていないカラムがありませんか？

質問の内容と症状からはこれぐらいしか思いつきませんでした

Comment: ありがとうございます。 なぜか、password,60というカラム名になっていて、これがおかしく、passwordに書き換えたら解決いたしました！